# jPlayer Safari 5.0.6 not playing audio (PHP download script)

Tags: php, javascript, safari, jplayer

I am having problems with jPlayer. Audio is playing fine in the latest version of Safari on Lion but I cannot get it to work in Safari 5.0.6.

I have the audio located outside of httpdocs for security, so have implemented a script to download the audio.

```
function playSong(id,title){

    $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("setMedia", { mp3: "/download.php?id=" + id });
    $("#jp_container .track-name").text(title);
    $("#jquery_jplayer").jPlayer("play", 0);

}
```

Download.php currently looks like this, and is a solution I found from another user on stackoverflow.

```
// array of support file types for download script and there mimetype
$mimeTypes = array(
    'doc' => 'application/msword',
    'pdf' => 'application/pdf',
    'mp3' => 'audio/mpeg'
);
// set the file here (best of using a $_GET[])
$file = "../song_files/mp3/$_GET[id].mp3";

// gets the extension of the file to be loaded for searching array above
$ext = explode('.', $file);
$ext = end($ext);

// gets the file name to send to the browser to force download of file
$fileName = explode("/", $file);
$fileName = end($fileName);

$fsize = filesize($file);
// opens the file for reading and sends headers to browser
$fp = fopen($file,"r") ;
header("Content-Type: ".$mimeTypes[$ext]);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
header('Content-Range: bytes');
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize); 

// reads file and send the raw code to browser     
while (! feof($fp)) {
    $buff = fread($fp,4096);
    echo $buff;
}
// closes file after whe have finished reading it
fclose($fp);
```

I understand that this may be something to do with the headers I am sending and the older version of Safari isn't processing them correctly, however, I can successfully download the file if I browse to download.php?id=1.

Any idea how I can see what jPlayer is doing, I.E. returning an error such as cannot find file? If somebody can point me in the right direction that would be appreciated.

Comment: We've encountered some very similar issues with audio on Safari 5.0.6... will keep you informed if we get anywhere!